# Divide the SQL table results by 1 - looping through the recorset

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have a sql query that outputs certain currency value. I need to extract that table to my excel worksheet and then divide the currency by 1. In my case, only the first currencies gets retrieved currently, and then rest just copies the same value as the first currency. Should I follow a different approach ?

```
       Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
       Set rst = conn.Execute("SELECT [midpoint] " _
                    & "FROM[FOREX] " _
                    & "Where currency in ('CAD','AUD','EURO','HKD','JPY','MYR','NZD','SGD','THB') and " _
                    & "xdate=(select max(xdate) FROM [FOREX] where currency  in ('CAD','AUD','EURO','HKD','JPY','MYR','NZD','SGD','THB'))")
    If rst.EOF Then
      Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim rstCAD As Double

     Sheets("Tables").Range("FX2USD_CAD").Value = 1 / rst(0)
     Sheets("Tables").Range("FX2USD_AUD").Value = 1 / rst(1)
     Sheets("Tables").Range("FX2USD_EURO").Value = 1 / rst(2)
    Sheets("Tables").Range("FX2USD_HKD").Value = 1 / rst(3)
    Sheets("Tables").Range("FX2USD_JPY").Value = 1 / rst(4)    
    Sheets("Tables").Range("FX2USD_MYR").Value = 1 / rst(5)
    Sheets("Tables").Range("FX2USD_NZD").Value = 1 / rst(6)
    Sheets("Tables").Range("FX2USD_SGD").Value = 1 / rst(7)
    Sheets("Tables").Range("FX2USD_THB").Value = 1 / rst(8)
    Sheets("Tables").Range("FXLastUpdated").Value = Now

End If
```

Comment: Am I missing something? You are dividing by one? That is mathematically the same as your value (x/1=x). You mean you are taking the inverse of the currency? I.e. 1/x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rst(1)` attempts to read the *2nd* column of the first row, but you only have one column.

You need to call `.movenext` to move to the next row, you could loop but you have a predefined order of values so instead you could:

```
dim sht as worksheet: set sht = Sheets("Tables")

with sht 
   .Range("FX2USD_CAD").Value = 1 / rst(0)
   rst.movenext

   .Range("FX2USD_AUD").Value = 1 / rst(0)
   rst.movenext

   ... and so on
end with
```

You need to modify your SQL & add an `ORDER BY` clause to make sure the order of rows in the query results match the order of `FX2USD_CAD_*` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You must wrap your code into a `while-loop`:

```
i = 0
While Not rs.EOF ' keep cycling untill all rows have been retrived
    ' write the value of the i-th cell
    Sheets("Tables").offset(index).Range("FX2USD_CAD").Value = 1 / rst(0) 
    ' one line per column (FX2USD_AUD, FX2USD_EURO, ...)
    rst.MoveNext ' retrive the next row
    i = i + 1 ' mode the index by one
Wend
```

and, of course, close your statement when you're finished: rst.Close